# Laggy bottomsheet on Huawei (Honor 8X)

Tags: java, android

My simple bottom sheet works perfect on my Honor 5A(API 22), API 23 and API 30 emulators, but when I am trying to test it on my Honor 8X with android 10 i am getting skipped frames! Please, help me! I tried to launch release version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added `android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:largeHeap="true"` in my manifest.xml and all works perfect!